# How to get the color hex value of a UI control in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Lets say i have this rectangle with the name Rect

```
<Rectangle Name="Rect" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Fill="#FF0099BB"/>
```

How can i get the Fill value of it, in code?
I tried 
`return Rect.Fill.ToString()` but all i got was the namespace and class and object of that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cast it to a SolidColorBrush;

```
 var someBrash = Rect.Fill as SolidColorBrush;
    if(someBrash != null)
        someColor = brush.Color
```